# If $a+b+c=1,$ prove $\frac{1-bc}{2a}+\frac{1-ca}{2b}+\frac{1-ab}{2c}+5\ge \sqrt{\frac{a}{bc}+6}+\sqrt{\frac{b}{ca}+6}+\sqrt{\frac{c}{ab}+6}$

Tags: inequality

Ì $a,b,c>0: a+b+c=1,$ prove that$$\frac{1-bc}{2a}+\frac{1-ca}{2b}+\frac{1-ab}{2c}+5\ge \sqrt{\frac{a}{bc}+6}+\sqrt{\frac{b}{ca}+6}+\sqrt{\frac{c}{ab}+6}.$$
I tried to used some inequalities as AM-GM, C-S,... without success.

For example, the followings are not true iff $a=b\rightarrow 0$  $$\frac{1-bc}{2a}+\frac{1-ca}{2b}+\frac{1-ab}{2c}+5\ge \sqrt{3}\sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{cab}+18}.$$
$$3\sqrt[3]{\frac{1-bc}{2a}.\frac{1-ca}{2b}.\frac{1-ab}{2c}}+5\ge \sqrt{\frac{a}{bc}+6}+\sqrt{\frac{b}{ca}+6}+\sqrt{\frac{c}{ab}+6}.$$
Also, by condition $1-bc=(a+b+c)^2-bc=a^2+b^2+c^2+bc+2a(b+c),$ we will prove$$(a^2+b^2+c^2)\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{2a}+\sum_{cyc}\frac{bc}{2a}+7\ge \sqrt{\frac{a}{bc}+6}+\sqrt{\frac{b}{ca}+6}+\sqrt{\frac{c}{ab}+6},$$How can I continue this approach ?

**Update**
Is the following true ?$$\frac{1-bc}{2a}+\frac{1-ca}{2b}+\frac{1-ab}{2c}+5\ge \sqrt{3}\sqrt{\frac{a}{bc}+6+\frac{b}{ca}+6+\frac{c}{ab}+6}?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Proof.**

By multiplying $abc$  for both side of the OP, we will prove
$$\sum_{cyc}bc(1-bc)+10abc\ge 2\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{a^2bc+6(abc)^2},$$which AM-GM imply that it is enough to prove$$\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2\left[c(a+b)^2(a+c)(b+c)-2abc(a+b)\right]\ge 0.$$From now, SOS helps very well.

Can you end it now?

Indeed, we apply AM-GM as
\begin{align*}
4\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{a^2bc+6(abc)^2}&=2\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{4abc}{b+c}\cdot(a^2+6abc)(b+c)}\\
&\le \sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{4abc}{b+c}+(a^2+6abc)(b+c)\right)\\
&\le 4abc\sum\limits_{cyc}a\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{1}{b+c}+12abc+\sum_{cyc}ab(a+b)\\
&\le 21abc+4abc\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{b+c}+\sum\limits_{cyc}bc. 
\end{align*}
Take cyclic sum on this estimation, we need to prove$$2\sum_{cyc}bc(1-bc)+20abc\ge 21abc+4abc\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{b+c}+ab+bc+ca,$$
or
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}a\sum\limits_{cyc}bc-9abc+2\left(abc\sum\limits_{cyc}a-\sum_{cyc}b^2c^2\right)\ge 4abc\left(\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{b+c}-\frac{3}{2}\right),$$
$$\iff\sum_{cyc}c(a-b)^2-\sum_{cyc}c^2(a-b)^2\ge 2abc\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a-b)^2}{(a+c)(b+c)}.$$
Let\begin{align*}
S_{c}=c(a+b)^2(a+c)(b+c)-2abc(a+b),\\
S_{a}=a(a+b)(a+c)(b+c)^2-2abc(b+c),\\
S_{b}=b(a+b)(a+c)^2(b+c)-2abc(c+a).   
\end{align*}
WLOG, assume that $a\ge b \ge c.$

Notice that
\begin{align*}
S_{a}&=a(b+c)\left(ab+ac+bc-abc-2bc\right)\\
&=a(b+c)\left[c(a-b)+ab(1-c)\right]> 0,\\
S_{b}&=b(c+a)\left(ab+ac+bc-abc-2ac\right)\\
&=a(b+c)\left[a(b-c)+bc(1-a)\right]> 0,    
\end{align*}
$\implies S_{a}+S_{b}>0.$

By $SOS$ theorem, it is enough to prove $S_{c}+S_{b}>0,$ which means$$(ab+bc+ca-abc)(ac+bc+bc+ba)-2abc(2a+b+c)>0.$$
It is equivalent to$$a^2b^2(a+b)+2c^2b^2(c+b)+a^2c^2(a+c)+abc\ge 3a^2bc,$$
or\begin{align*}
&a^3(b^2+c^2)+a^2(b^3+c^3)+2c^2b^2(c+b)+abc(a+b+c)^2\ge 3a^2bc(a+b+c),    
\end{align*}
which is true since\begin{align*}
&a^3(b^2+c^2)+a^2(b^3+c^3)+2c^2b^2(c+b)+abc(a+b+c)^2\\
&>a^3(b^2+bc+c^2)+a^2(b^3+c^3+2bc(b+c))\\
&>3bca^3+3a^2bc(b+c)\\
&=3a^2bc(a+b+c).   
\end{align*}
We end proof here. Equality holds at $a=b=c=\dfrac{1}{3}.$

About $SOS$ theorem, see [here.](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/q1h80127p458535)

Comment: I did not downvote you. Just remember: Write clear proof or you can write "Some thoughts". Best regard!

Comment: @TATA box Can you explain, how did you use AM-GM?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg. I added and will update the nice proof for the rest later

Comment: @TATAbox Can you explain why you apply as that ?

Comment: @Anonymous I just try some option and it worked.